# Matching 2 regex patterns with 1 pattern in the front or back

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regex that matches 2 patterns with 1 pattern in the front or back, but the first array return 2 empty indexes. Why is it doing that, and how would I stop it from doing that?

```
$text = "i did";
preg_match("~(?:(did) (.+)|(.+) (did))~", $text, $match);
print_r($match);

echo "<br>";

$text = "did i";
preg_match("~(?:(did) (.+)|(.+) (did))~", $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => i did [1] => [2] => [3] => i [4] => did ) 
Array ( [0] => did i [1] => did [2] => i )
```

**Want Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => i did [1] => i [2] => did ) 
Array ( [0] => did i [1] => did [2] => i )
```

Comment: If all you want to do is get rid of the empty values you could do `array_filter($match)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [*branch reset*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|...)`:

> **Alternatives inside a branch reset group share the same capturing groups.** The syntax is `(?|regex)` where `(?|` opens the group and regex is any regular expression.

Your `preg_match` will look like:

```
preg_match("~(?|(did) (.+)|(.+) (did))~", $text, $match);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ClTS17)

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => i did
    [1] => i
    [2] => did
)
```

I guess your regex is a sample one. If you need to match a word after or before `did`, use the `\w` shorthand class:

```
preg_match("~(?|(did) (\w+)|(\w+) (did))~", $text, $match);
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/Uc4uVb)

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version that behaves as you wish:

```
$text1 = "i did";
preg_match("~(did|\w+(?= did)) (did|(?<=did )\w+)~", $text1, $match1);
print_r($match1);

$text2 = "did i";
preg_match("~(did|\w+(?= did)) (did|(?<=did )\w+)~", $text2, $match2);
print_r($match2);

$text3 = "did x, x did";
preg_match_all("~(did|\w+(?= did)) (did|(?<=did )\w+)~", $text3, $match3);
print_r($match3);

$text4 = "a a";
preg_match("~(did|\w+(?= did)) (did|(?<=did )\w+)~", $text4, $match4);
print_r($match4);
```

An online version [here](http://ideone.com/AtS529)

**Note**: the regex takes advantage of the behaviour of OR in regex, the first results matched stop the regex engine to go further.

Comment: This will also match `a a` and loses the combination of 'did x, x did'.

Comment: @moorscode: thank you for point out some failure points, i've fixed using lookahead and lookbehind. Anyway the chosen solution is better (i'm glad to learn new tricks here in SO)